# The z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index

Problem is that the `#one` overlaps with `#three`. Why is the `z-index` not working?

```css
#one {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

Comment: how far have you given z-index ? try something above 99.

Comment: check this example https://jsfiddle.net/r1yvga44/
it works even in your code.

Comment: `z-index` is working in your code. 'one' and 'three' are overlapping because they are positioned in the same place since you have given `position` and `top` values for 'one'. If you add a `background-color` to #one, you can see how z-idex works

Comment: And what seems to be the problem? Everything works as it should...

Comment: If you don't want them to overlap just remove the CSS. Everything is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>#one{position:relative; top:35px; z-index: 1;background:white}
#three{
z-index:-3; background:white}
</style>
</head>
<body>

       <div id="one">one</div>
       <div>two</div>
       <div id="three">three</div>
   </body>
</html>
```